# ROS2 rqt_tf_tree emits service not available, waiting again

Tags: ros, ros2, tf2, tf-tree, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS2 eloquent on Ubuntu 18.04 and just performed a `sudo apt-get install ros-eloquent-rqt-tf-tree` and tried running the command in the terminal. The first time I ran it I received the error `qt_gui_main() found no plugin matching "rqt_tf_tree.tf_tree.RosTfTree"`. I then ran the same rqt_tf_tree command with `--force-discover` and after that, I began receiving `service not available, waiting again...` repeatedly each time I ran it. Both /tf and /tf_static are being published to by the ROS2 robot state publisher. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349175/ros2-rqt_tf_tree-emits-service-not-available,-waiting-again.../) by [mequi](https://answers.ros.org/users/49860/mequi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2020-04-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) on 2020-04-15**:
I have experienced exactly the same issue (ubuntu 18.04, ROS eloquent). There is also a related [issue on the rqt-tf-tree GitHub page](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_tf_tree/issues/20)  and another similar [question on ROS-Answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/341015/how-to-run-rqt-with-ubuntu-and-eloquent-service-not-available/?answer=349550#post-id-349550).

Unfortunately, none of these provides a solution to this issue and I was not able to come up with one either.

From what I know `tf` is still a work in progress in ROS eloquent, thus this currently might even be the "expected" behavior, as some relevant parts might still be missing. (?)

I would really appreciate it if someone could confirm that this is i fact true or rather a configuration issue/bug.

**Comment by [webvenky](https://answers.ros.org/users/22361/webvenky/) on 2020-04-28**:
Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After looking a little deeper into this issue, I will try to form an answer from my findings:

Currently, there is only preliminary support for `tf2` in ROS 2, and although `rqt_tf_free` has been released, some parts of `tf2` are apparently still a work in progress.

In order to work properly, `rqt_tf_tree` relies on the `tf2_frames` service, which however is not yet available in the latest release of `tf2_ros` (0.12.5).  This pending dependency is also pointed out [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_tf_tree/pull/13#issue-342953853).
However, the corresponding pull request to reactivate the frame graph service in `tf2_ros` (https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/pull/198), is still open.

Though this will probably be resolved in one the upcoming releases, I would find it really useful if this could be mentioned somewhere in the readme.

In the meantime, you might want to take a look at `view_frames` in the `tf2_tools` package (https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/tree/ros2/tf2_tools) that allows you to visualize your tf-tree in a similar way. (At the time writing, `tf2_tools` is not yet available in the package repository, so you need to install it from source.)

**Note:** if the `rqt_tf_tree` plugin prevents your rqt-GUI from opening, you simply need to reset your config by `rqt --clear-config` (see this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/341015/how-to-run-rqt-with-ubuntu-and-eloquent-service-not-available/#349550))

---

Originally posted by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) with karma: 218 on 2020-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1